# Unity Slider fill keeps disappearing on start

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I'm following the Survival Shooter on Youtube and I got some annoying and magically glitch even after I already made the part work. On the day that I made the `Slider`, it was working fine. Now, the fill keeps disappearing even if the value is 100. Also the code they used for initializing the `Slider` and `Image` isn't working now so I looked for a different code and it's working now. I'm using version 2019.3.0f6. This is my code.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class PlayerHealth : MonoBehaviour{
    int initHp = 100;
    public int currentHp;
    public Slider hpSlider;
    public Image dmgImg;
    AudioClip deathClip;
    float flashSpd = 5f;
    Color flashColor = new Color(1f, 0f, 0f, 0.1f);

    Animator animator;
    AudioSource playerAudio;
    PlayerMovement playerMovement;
    PlayerShooting playerShooting;
    bool isDead;
    bool isDamaged;

    void Awake() {
        animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
        playerAudio = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
        playerMovement = GetComponent<PlayerMovement>();
        playerShooting = GetComponentInChildren<PlayerShooting>();
        currentHp = initHp;
    }

    void Start(){
        if (GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag ("hpSlider")) {
            hpSlider = (Slider) FindObjectOfType(typeof (Slider));
        }
        if (GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag ("dmgImg")) {
            dmgImg = (Image) FindObjectOfType(typeof (Image));
        }
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update(){
        if(dmgImg != null){
            if(isDamaged){
                dmgImg.color = flashColor;
                Debug.Log("flash color");
            }else{
                dmgImg.color = Color.Lerp(dmgImg.color, Color.clear, flashSpd * Time.deltaTime);
            }
        }
        dmgImg.color = Color.Lerp(dmgImg.color, Color.clear, flashSpd * Time.deltaTime);
        isDamaged = false;
        Debug.Log("currentHp: "+currentHp+" sliderVal: "+hpSlider.value);
    }

    public void TakeDamage(int amt){
        isDamaged = true;
        currentHp -= amt;

        // hpSlider.value = currentHp;
        Debug.Log("currentHp: "+currentHp+" sliderVal: "+hpSlider.value);

        playerAudio.Play();

        if(currentHp <= 0 && !isDead){
            Death();    
        }
    }

    public void Death(){
        isDead = true;
        animator.SetTrigger("Die");

        // playerAudio.clip =   deathClip;
        // playerAudio.Play();

        playerMovement.enabled = false;
        playerShooting.enabled = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: nothing like a good old -1 for a StackOverflow question.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `[Range()]` attribute, it works like so:

`[Range(0, 100)] public int currentHp`

Sorry for not commenting, as I see this is not an answer but my rep is too low (:

Comment: will try to do that